# Why won't this MySQL stored procedure work?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have made an SP that tries to remove items in order of caducity date it works assuming that different batches have different caducity dates, I need to sell the ones that are closer to expiriation, but I can't see why it won't let me add this SP.

My SP gets 3 parameters: `id_nombre`, `cant` and `fecha` where `id_nombre` is the id of the product, `cant` is the quantity that I want to sell and `fecha` is the date of the sale. My SP is this:

```
DELIMITER $$
BEGIN
DECLARE cantidad_previa int; /*I use this var to store the total of products before the sell.*/
DECLARE lote int; /*stores the id of the batch that is closer to expire*/
DECLARE aux_cont int; /*its a counter that stores the ramaining products to sell*/
DECLARE cant_lote int; /*stores how many products has a batch.*/
SET aux_cont = cant;
select cantidad into cantidad_previa from productos where id_producto=id_nombre;
if cantidad_previa>cant
then
    WHILE aux_cont>0 do
    select id_lote into lote FROM lotes where id_producto=id_nombre and cantidad>0 order by fecha_exp limit 1;
    select cantidad into cant_lote from lotes where id_lote=lote;
    if cant_lote>aux_cont
    then
        set cant_lote = cant_lote - aux_cont;
        update lotes set cantidad = cant_lote where id_lote = lote;
        set aux_cont = 0;
        else
        update lotes set cantidad = 0 where id_lote=lote;
        set aux_cont = aux_cont - cant_lote;
    end if;
    end while;
    INSERT INTO registro_ventas VALUES (NULL, id_nombre, cant, fecha);
    else
    return
end if;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

What I am trying to do is verify if the total amount of products is greater than the amount of asked products. Then, I proceed to verify if the asked amount is less than the amount of a determined batch, if that's the case I just subtract them from that batch, if not I need to put to 0 that batch and start with the next one closer to expire. Finally, when I have that done I need to add that sale to the sales table (registro_ventas).

Edit: I could do it this way

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `registrarventa` (id_nombre INT, cant INT, fecha DATE)
BEGIN

DECLARE cantidad_previa int;
DECLARE lote int;
DECLARE aux_cont int;
DECLARE cant_lote int;

SET aux_cont = cant;
select cantidad into cantidad_previa from productos where id_producto=id_nombre;
if cantidad_previa>cant
then
    WHILE aux_cont>0 do
    select id_lote into lote FROM lotes where id_producto=id_nombre and cantidad>0 order by fecha_exp limit 1;
    select cantidad into cant_lote from lotes where id_lote=lote;
    if cant_lote>aux_cont
    then
        set cant_lote = cant_lote - aux_cont;
        update lotes set cantidad = cant_lote where id_lote = lote;
        set aux_cont = 0;
        else
        update lotes set cantidad = 0 where id_lote=lote;
        set aux_cont = aux_cont - cant_lote;
    end if;
    end while;
    INSERT INTO registro_ventas VALUES (NULL, id_nombre, cant, fecha);
end if;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: your comments are not helping. Try remove them and provide some background information on what you want to do with the procedure so we can understand you.

Comment: Don't you need to end `end if` with `;`?

Comment: Done, I tried to be more especific Tim3880, and nope I already tried that Uueerdo :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing your syntax

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (IN para1 varcahr(255), OUT param2 INT)
```

This statement needs to go before the `BEGIN` and after the `Delimiter`.

For more information on creating a stored procedure please refer [Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html)

Comment: My bad I didn't wrote that I'm using WAMP-> phpMyAdmin

http://prntscr.com/74y6sl

but I'll try to add it that way.